# Loop through dataframe variables in R

Tags: arrays, r, string, loops, dataframe

I have a few dataframes with only a few variables different from each other. Mostly they are the same. 
I would like to prepare the variables in a loop, so I do not have to specify each and every variable for all my dataframes separately. I'm however running into some issues.

```
clist <- c("data", "data_error", "data_RT")
```

I first made a list of the names of my dataframes

```
for (i in clist) {
i$ID <- as.factor(i$ID)
i$TMS <- as.factor(i$TMS)
i$bias<- as.numeric(i$bias)
 ... }
```

The I try to loop over all the variables I want to prepare. This is however not possible and I get an error message saying:

```
Error in i$ID : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I tried google for help, but I did not understand the explanations for it :( Could you help me understand what I'm doing wrong and how I could solve it?

Comment: The $-operator doesn't work dynamically. Use i[,"ID"] <- as.factor(i[,"ID"]) ....

Comment: also you need the dataframes in clist as object_names and not as strings.

Comment: Hi Andre! Thanks for the hint! It however still produces an error. I changed it now to: `clist <- c(data, data_error, data_RT)
for (i in clist) {
i[,"ID"] <- as.factor(i[,"ID"])
}` but it tells me `Error in `[.default`(i, , "ID") : incorrect number of dimensions`. This confuses me, because if I just replace the "i" with "data" (as I intend the loop to do) `data[,"ID"] <- as.factor(data[,"ID"])`, it does work... Any thoughts on where the dimension mismatch might stem from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a list of dataframes instead of a vector of names:

```
clist <- list(data, data_error, data_RT)
```

Then loop through the list:

```
for (i in 1:length(clist)) {
clist[[i]]$ID <- as.factor(clist[[i]]$ID)
clist[[i]]$TMS <- as.factor(clist[[i]]$TMS)
clist[[i]]$bias<- as.numeric(clist[[i]]$bias)
 ... }
```

Afterwards, you can use

```
list2env(clist,globalenv())
```

to put the dataframes back into your global environment. I would advise you to just keep them inside the list, though.